# Negating a Regular Expression for string replacement

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

I have the following code that can replace the email address in a String in Java:

```
addressStr.replaceFirst("([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)@((\\[[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+\\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})", "")
```

So, a string with `John Smith <john@smith.com>` would become `John Smith <>`. How do I negate it so that it will instead replace all that doesn't match the email address and have the final result as just `john@smith.com`?

I tried to put in the `^` and `?<=` at the front but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it's not the regex you need to change but the calling code. Your regex matches the e-mail address (in a weird way), and the `replace()` removes it from the string.

So just use

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)@((\\[[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+\\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(addressStr);
if (regexMatcher.find()) {
    address = regexMatcher.group();
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it throws me a `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found`. When I print `regexMatcher.matches()`, it returns false but `regexMatcher.find()` returns true. That's weird. What are their differences and why does `regexMatcher.group();` throw me that exception?

Comment: Uh, sorry, you do need to do a `find()` first. Will edit. `matcher()` doesn't work because it needs to match the entire string.

Comment: I think you meant `matches()` in the comment above, not `matcher()`, Tim.

Answer (score 3):

The complete Java regex for catching e-mails would be as follows:

```
"(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])"
```

Take a look at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.4.1 for more info on this.

A bit complicated but it is valid for all known and valid emails formats (yours do not allows mails like bob+bib@gmail.com which are valid).

For your problem, as stated multiple times, just find (stealing Tim Pietzcker piece of code):

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(addressStr);
foundMatch = regexMatcher.find();
```

Comment: At least one person who points out the obvious flaw before getting to worked up in small details. I've seen way too many websites with just completely broken validators it's not even funny any more :/ I'd love to give +2 if I could..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But both regexMatcher.find(); and regexMatcher.matches(); return a boolean instead of a string. How can I get the string of the email address from the source string instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
String mailId = Pattern.compile(regexp, Pattern.LITERAL).matcher(addressStr).group();
```

Idea here is to get the matched string rather than trying to replace everything else with blank. You can extract the pattern into a field if this operation is repetitive.

Comment: `Pattern.LITERAL` causes the pattern string to be treated as a literal string, but this problem clearly requires it to be treated as a regex.  Also, `matcher(String)` merely creates a `Matcher` object, it doesn't try to apply the regex--as others have said, you need to follow up by calling (in this case) `find()`.  As it is, your code will always throw an `IllegalStateException`.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't replace.... use match(es) instead.